# Filtrado de datos con pandas pero con múltiples filas

Tags: python, pandas, visualización-de-datos

Estoy trabajando con un archivo csv desde python, puede encontrarlo en el siguiente link: https://www.kaggle.com/ruchi798/movies-on-netflix-prime-video-hulu-and-disney?select=MoviesOnStreamingPlatforms_updated.csv
Y quiero calcular el número de peliculas por año, mi método fue hacer lo siguiente:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
peliculas_2010=Poyecto_EDA_DQ[(Poyecto_EDA_DQ["Year"]==2010)]
peliculas_1999=Poyecto_EDA_DQ[(Poyecto_EDA_DQ["Year"]==1999)]
```

Pero este método es muy rudimentario pues me tocaria hacer esto mismo para todos los años y son demasiados años, mi pregunta es si existe algún método mejor de hacer esto sin tener que hacerlo año por año
Gracias!

Comment: Un ciclo `for` o agrupa las películas por año

Comment: Puedes ser un poco más especifico?

Comment: Puedes realizar un ciclo `for` para iterar en todos los años o ta,bien puedes agrupar los datos por año así `años = df.groupby("Year").sum(); print(años)`

Comment: @Christian esa función te sirve, pero debe ser un `count()` en vez de un `sum()`, también lo puedes hacer de la siguiente manera --> `df.Year.value_counts()` [value_counts](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.value_counts.html#pandas.DataFrame.value_counts)